# Rails 3: Custom Model Notices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

Currently I verify that there are no duplicated Members when trying to create a new Member and add it to a Team.

members_controller.rb

```
def create
  @team = current_team
  player = Player.find(params[:player_id])
  @member = @team.add_player(player.id)

  respond_to do |format|
     if @member.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@team, :notice => 'Member was successfully added.') }
        format.js { @current_member = @member }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @member, 
        :status => :created, :location => @member } 
     else
        format.html { redirect_to(@team, :notice => 'Member already exists.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @member.errors, 
        :status => :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

team.rb

```
def add_player(player_id)
    current_member = members.build(:player_id => player_id)
    current_member
end
```

I want to add some logic to my add_player method in team.rb that checks various properties of the player that is being added. This action will require multiple failure messages, other than 'Member already exists.' How do I do this in the Model layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller logic to display all errors from base worked. However, I was not able to add errors from the add_player method as Ben suggested. I instead created separate custom validations as such:

```
Team.rb

validate validation_name

def validation_name
  if condition
    errors.add_to_base "Error Message"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom errors on ActiveRecord models. These custom errors can have their own messages, which you can query in your controller if the save is not successful:

```
# app/models/team.rb
def add_player(player_id)
    current_member = members.build(:player_id => player_id)
    errors.add(:player_id, 'Custom error message here') if condition
    errors.add(:base, 'Custom error message here') if condition    
    current_member
end

# app/controllers/members_controller.rb
def create
  @team = current_team
  player = Player.find(params[:player_id])
  @member = @team.add_player(player.id)

  respond_to do |format|
     if @member.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@team, :notice => 'Member was successfully added.') }
        format.js { @current_member = @member }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @member, 
        :status => :created, :location => @member } 
     else
        format.html { redirect_to(@team, :notice => @member.errors.full_messages) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @member.errors, 
        :status => :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

More information on custom ActiveRecord validation errors here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html#M001725

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to implement this. All of the attributes I want to check are on the member. I have methods within the Team which figure out the conditions, so I have condition methods within the Team that I want to check. I tried using base, but it seemed like the condition was never tripped when I tried something like:
errors.add(:base, 'Custom error message here') if method_returns_one > 2

Comment: It seems the validations should occur on the member model, unless what you are checking is only valid or invalid in the context of a team. If the member object is not valid, neither will the team object, since the member is building through the team.

Comment: Also, in order for you to see the custom errors on team, you would have to call the add_player method at least once to do the calculations before you call save. It may be better to move these error checking into a method named "validate". Rails will automatically look for a method by this name when checking to see if a record is valid

Comment: What if I need properties of all the Members combined? I am counting the number of members that have a specific property and I need this number to perform the logic I need.

Comment: If the property is a database column, you can use the method generated by "has_many :members" to run a new ActiveRecord query. It would look like "self.members.where(conditions).count"

Comment: I'm having trouble getting that statement to work properly. To test it, I made a method in Team.rb called test as follows: 

'def test
  self.members.where(:property == 'Example').count
end'. This keeps returning just the count of members. In other methods, I have used identical logic to keep count of members with this property and these are returning the correct values.